# How can I get values from python file to my html?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask, debian

I'm trying to get values from my python file to my html.

Here's my form:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Direccion IP: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ address }}" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my python file:

```
def getinterfaces():
    with open('/etc/network/interfaces', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            found_address = line.find('address')
            if found_address != -1:
                address = line[found_address+len('address:'):]
                print 'Address: ', address
            return address
```

I tried with "FLASK" but nothing worked..

> I think my problem is in my path , because my project is in
>   "project/app/Mensajeria/views.py", my html is in:
>   "project/app/templates/test.html"

I'm importing Flask and everything, I have flask installed, I tried to reinstalled but nothing worked...

Comment: I think more info is needed here. Does running `getinterfaces` return the desired result? Any errors? Beyond that, there isn't enough flask setup here in the question to know if paths are configed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending the data to be served up on a webpage, using the HTML template, how about something like this?

```
@app.route('/test')
def showPage():
    # your code here
    address = # however you assign it
    return render_template('test.html', address=address)
```

In order to use a variable inside `{{}}` in a template, you'll have to pass that variable to the template, such as here with `return render_template('test.html', address=address)`.

If you need `address` to contain many things you can always send it as a `list` or `dict` and extract the individual variables you need in your template with `jinja`.  For example, if you need multiple `<div>` elements each containing an address:

#### python file

```
@app.route('/test')
def showPage():
    # your code here
    addresses = # however you assign it
    return render_template('test.html', addresses=addresses)
```

#### test.html

```
{% for address in addresses %}
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Direccion IP: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ address }}" >
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```